# database filtering null values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table consist of 96 columns.
And according to value of the first column only few has a value.

let say firs column ID 
for :Id 111752 only column number 9- 17 has some value.

How can I filter the null values when I have to deal with the item 111752?

Comment: what about `where aField is null`? You really need to get yourself a good book on SQL (or read a good online tutorial) if you don't know how to filter null values

Comment: I think your first problem is having a table with 96 columns. If most of the columns are usually blank, you need to re-visit your database schema.

Comment: @Barranka My understanding is he wants to filter out **columns** that are null for a particular row. This isn't something to solve with a WHERE clause - it's a schema problem.

Comment: @jcsanyi So a small piece of code on the front end that iterates over each row can help. Indeed the table is to wide and can use a big overhaul (a.k.a. normalization)

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not support conditionally selecting columns. If you're stuck with this database schema, your only option is to `SELECT *`, and then filter the resulting columns on the client side (PHP ?).

However - I think the real problem here is with your schema. If you've got a table with 96 columns, and most of them (or large groups of them) are usually NULL, then there's a problem with your database schema - that is, with the way you've grouped your data into tables.

Read up on database normalization, and think about how you could redesign your database.

- [Database Normalization on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
- [Database Normalization Basics](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)
- [An Introduction to Database Normalization](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/)